# Is there a way to break a line in the title attribute of a Tooltip component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tooltip

I want the following tooltip to display its title in two different rows:

```
<Tooltip title="Line1 Line2">
...
</Tooltip>
```

So that, when I hover it I get

Line 1
Line 2

I tried inserting `<br />`, `\n` and `&#13;` already with no success.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Could you please attach Tooltip component? You probably need to change logic in it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you use the title props (inside the Tooltip component), you could pass directly html or a component in it instead of giving string value. Example:

```js
<Tooltip title={<div><p>First Line</p><p>Second Line</p></div}>
...
</Tooltip>
```

With **React Component** :

```js
const ExampleComponent = () =>{
   return (
     <div>
       <p>First Line</p>
       <p>SecondLine</p>
     </div>
   )
}

... // Your rendered component
<Tooltip title={<ExampleComponent/>}>
...
</Tooltip>
```

Hope I could help !

Answer (score 0):

Just use this `&#013;`
It will break the line.

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortunately, it didn't work for me